# Why does MySQL select offset not work in pyspark?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

```
select distinct day 
from t1 
order by 1 desc limit 1,1
```

should return the second latest date in t1, but this error is thrown:

> ParseException:  mismatched input ',' expecting {, ';'}

Comment: I think SPARK does not have the same features as MySQL.  Can you try `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`?